# Regex распознать строку до условия

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть ли в регулярках способ распознать строку до определенных символов не включая сами символы?

К примеру, мой regex `/.*index[.]php[?]?/g`

на следующих строках :

```
http://localhost/esculape/www/index.php?a=10
http://localhost/esculape/www/index.php
```

находит :

```
http://localhost/esculape/www/index.php?
http://localhost/esculape/www/index.php
```

А мне нужна вся строка, но до `index.php?a=10`
тоесть в результате должно быть

```
http://localhost/esculape/www/
```

Ссылка на [мой пример](https://regex101.com/r/lF3aF9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться опережающей проверкой, если она поддерживается вашим диалектом регулярных выражений

```
/.*(?=index[.]php[?]?)/g
```